# Ansible - check mode with file module and dependent steps

Tags: directory, ansible

In my ansible playbooks, I often have steps like "create a directory and then do something in it", e.g.:

```
- name: Create directory
  file:
    path: "{{ tomcat_directory }}"
    state: directory

- name: Extract tomcat
  unarchive:
    src: 'tomcat.tar.gz'
    dest: '{{ tomcat_directory }}'
```

When I run this playbook, it works perfectly fine. However, when I run this playbook in check mode, the first step succeeds (folder would have been created), but the second one fails, because the folder does not exist.

Is there any way how I could write steps like these where I create folder and then operate in it while also being able to run the playbook in check mode (without skipping such steps)?

Comment: Root cause for this issue: ansible-playbook <playbookname> -C option will just do the sanity run (without the actual SSH'ing to hosts), so will not be creating actual directory or file in the client nodes.
 
This is a known issue for now, when executing playbooks using option "-C" with File module.

Answer (score 3):

Check mode can be a bit of a pain. You only really have two options:

1) Add conditionals to tasks to skip them in check mode, which you don't want to do. For reference tho:

```
when: not ansible_check_mode
```

2) You can change the behaviour of the task in check mode. If you set `check_mode: no` on a task, then in check mode it will behave as it would in a normal run. That is to say, despite you specifying check mode, it will actually perform the task and create the dir if it does not already exist. You have to make a choice if you are happy for a given task to run for real in check mode, so it tends to only be appropriate for low risk tasks, but does provide you a route to continue testing the rest of your playbook that is dependent on the step in question.

[Ansible Check Mode Docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_checkmode.html)

Comment: I see. Even the docs state "if you have steps that use conditionals that depend on the results of prior commands, it may be less useful for you", so it seems like there are no other options. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You could make use of the `ignore_errors` task option, along with the `ansible_check_mode` variable, to ignore errors with your `Extract tomcat` task only when running in check mode, e.g.:

```
- name: Create directory
  file:
    path: "{{ tomcat_directory }}"
    state: directory

- name: Extract tomcat
  unarchive:
    src: 'tomcat.tar.gz'
    dest: '{{ tomcat_directory }}'
  ignore_errors: "{{ ansible_check_mode }}"
```

Running this in check mode will show the `Extract tomcat` task failed due to `dest` not existing.  However, instead of failing the playbook, the task failure will be marked as ignored and playbook execution will continue.

Answer (score 0):

An option would be to "*register: result*" and test "*when: result.state is defined*"

```
- name: Create directory
  file:
    path: "{{ tomcat_directory }}"
    state: directory
  register: result

- name: Extract tomcat
  unarchive:
    src: 'tomcat.tar.gz'
    dest: '{{ tomcat_directory }}'
  when: result.state is defined
```

Comment: Thank for your answer, but as I said, I don't want to skip the steps that use the directory, as that will be most of them in the playbook. Thus check mode while skipping almost all steps would be rather useless.

Comment: What is your expectation? What should be the result of running *unarchive* with non-existent directory *dest* ?

Comment: That was the purpose of my question. If the directory did exist, the unarchive in checkmode would not fail, but still perform some checks without extracting the files (I reckon it at least checks that the source file exists), so my expectations were that it would behave in the same way.